# "Attempting to reference a deleted function"

Tags: c++, boost, vector

This code gives me the error "attempting a reference a deleted function" on the specified line. What is my mistake and how do I correct it?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <vector>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

static char *port[] = { "54997", "34997", "57997", "58997" };
std::vector<udp::socket> sockets;

void getsockets()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), "127.0.0.1", port[i]);

        udp::socket socket(io_service);
        socket.open(udp::v4());

        udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
        socket.bind(sender_endpoint);
        sockets.push_back(socket);    //this line seems to be the one causing the error
    }
}

int main()
{

    getsockets();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with boost::asio but the error most likely indicates that `udp::socket` is not copyable,  which would make sense.  Try `sockets.emplace_back( std::move(socket) );` , or you could build the socket in the vector in the first place.

Comment: Looks like you can't copy or move a `udp::socket`. Let's see what the documentation says. Back inna minute.

Comment: Is it a problem that the `io_service` dies at the end of the loop?

Comment: @user4581301 [Check here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/basic_datagram_socket.html).  Copy, no.  Move, yes.

Comment: Not sure I can word this better than @MattMcNabb did in his first comment. Only thing I can add is the move constructor popped up in version 1.47.

Comment: @MattMcNabb `sockets.emplace_back( std::move(socket) );` gives me an access violation.

Comment: @chrisvj find out whether the socket still needs the `io_service` after it has been added to the vector

Comment: @MattMcNabb as does building it in the vector with `sockets.push_back(udp::socket(io_service));` and `sockets.emplace_back(std::move(udp::socket(io_service)));`

Comment: The io_service needs to hang around. You need it to run the background threads and callbacks later.

Comment: And I think you only need one, not one per socket.

Comment: Try `sockets.emplace_back(io_service);` to create the socket directly in the vector, and then open and bind. Something like `sockets.back().open();` if you aren't worried about another thread adding to `sockets`.

Comment: If the `io_service` needs to hang around then you cannot make it a local variable to the loop, obviously

Comment: @user4581301 `sockets.emplace_back(io_service);` would just put the io_service object in the vector, rather than creating a socket object and putting that in the vector.

Comment: @chrisvj No, a `std::vector<udp::socket>` can only contain `udp::socket` objects.  Emplace functions mean "make an object of the appropriate type, using these as constructor arguments".

Comment: @MattMcNabb oh, that seemed to have been the problem. I moved io_service to the global scope and it runs fine! Submit as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Chris, consider pulling `udp::resolver resolver(io_service);` out of the loop as well. No need to make it global, bit no point making the same resolver over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The `io_service` is used by the socket during the socket's lifetime, so it cannot be a local variable to your loop.  It must have the same lifetime (or longer) as your `vector`.
2. The `udp::socket` is not copyable. It doesn't make much sense to talk about copying a socket. However it is moveable, so you could either emplace the socket directly into the vector, or move it into the vector, e.g.:

   `sockets.emplace_back( std::move(socket) );`

NB. I'm not familiar with boost::asio particulaly, so anyone who wants to edit this answer is welcome.

Comment: Question, Matt, why not just `sockets.emplace_back(io_service);`? Why construct and move the temp? Easier use while finishing up the initialization?

Comment: I was going for minimal changes to OP's code. Of course it is also viable to do what you say and then do `sockets.back().open`... and so on

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering if there was some tactical advantage I'd overlooked.